# Change each visible src to it's data attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$("[data-musterfull]:visible").each(function(){
    var bild = $(this).data('musterfull'); // fine till here
    $(this).attr('src', data); // this isn't working
});
```

How to fix the not working part?

Comment: Well what is the `data` variable? Did you mean `$(this).attr('src', bild);`

Comment: I think `data` is a typo - do you mean `bild` instead?

Comment: Perhaps this `$(this).atr('src',bild)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is because you've defined the variable named `bild`, not `data`.

Also note you can make the logic more succinct by providing a function to `attr()`, like this:

```
$("[data-musterfull]:visible").attr('src', function() {
  return $(this).data('musterfull');
});
```

Comment: Yeah was a typo, I'm very long awake now, I still will check because you were first xD

Comment: Normally I wouldn't answer as it's a basic typo, but hopefully this shows how you can improve the logic too

Answer (score 0):

Should be

```
$("[data-musterfull]:visible").each(function(){
    var bild = $(this).data('musterfull');
    $(this).attr('src', bild); 
});
```

You should pass the 'bild' variable to the attr('src') function instead of 'data'.